# Vuetify v-select will not close

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've done everything I know, and for some reason my `v-select` won't close after you open it.

Specifically if you click the first `v-select` and then tab out of it, you can't close that `v-select` anymore. That's the same thing I'm getting.

How can I force the close of the `v-select` after it loses focus?

I just realized that the same result is happening on the Vuetify website. So I copied their codepen and am adding it here:

[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/Trimakas/pen/oQmNXv?&editable=true&editors=101)

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Yep, this ended up being a bug that looks like its going to be fixed shortly.. [Here is the issue in GitHub](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5774)

Comment: Can't really see your code there, nor is there a combo box.  Are you sure we can see it without auth?  Better to distill down to a simple example on codesandbox.io to show what you're having trouble with.

Comment: @JimB. hey Jim, thanks.. I added a code pen with sample code. Come to find out this looks like a bug with Vuetify as the sample code is from an example on their website!

Comment: Sure does look like a vuetify bug.  The code couldn't be simpler.  You might try attaching to keypress/blur events to see if you can workaround, but my first read of the v-select component didn't show any controls for opening/closing it.

Comment: @JimB. yep Jim it is.. I opened an issue with Vuetify and they've confirmed the bug and looks like they are fixing. Updated the OP